# Scraping URLs with Python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get a python selenium script working that should do the following:

> 1. Take text file, BookTitle.txt that is a list of Book Titles.
> 2. Using Python/Selenium then searches the site, GoodReads.com for that title.
> 3. Takes the URL for the result and makes a new .CSV file with column 1=book title and column 2=Site URL
> 4. I hope that we can get this working, then please help me with step by step to get it to run.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
#from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys
import csv
import time
import json

class Book:
    def __init__(self, title, url):
        self.title = title
        self.url = url
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([self.title, self.url])

url = 'https://www.goodreads.com/'

def create_csv_file():
    header = ['Title', 'URL']
    with open('/home/l/gDrive/AudioBookReviews/WebScraping/GoodReadsBooksNew.csv', 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
        wr = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        wr.writerow(header)

def read_from_txt_file():
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('/home/l/gDrive/AudioBookReviews/WebScraping/BookTitles.txt', encoding='utf-8')]
    return lines

def init_selenium():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage') 
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/l/gDrive/AudioBookReviews/WebScraping/chromedriver",  chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(30)
    driver.get('https://www.goodreads.com/search?q=')

def search_for_title(title):
    search_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search_query_main"]')
    search_field.clear()
    search_field.send_keys(title)
    search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[1]/input[3]')
    search_button.click()

def scrape_url():
    try:
        url = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.bookTitle').get_attribute('href')
    except:
        url = "N/A"

    return url

def write_into_csv_file(vendor):
   with open('/home/l/gDrive/AudioBookReviews/WebScraping/GoodReadsBooksNew.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
        wr = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        wr.writerow(list(vendor))

create_csv_file()
titles = read_from_txt_file()    
init_selenium()

for title in titles:
    search_for_title(title)
    url = scrape_url()
    book = Book(title, url)
    write_into_csv_file(book)
```

Running the above, I get the following errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/l/gDrive/AudioBookReviews/WebScraping/GoodreadsScraper.py",
>   line 68, in 
>       init_selenium()   File "/home/l/gDrive/AudioBookReviews/WebScraping/GoodreadsScraper.py",
>   line 41, in init_selenium
>       driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/l/gDrive/AudioBookReviews/WebScraping/chromedriver",
>   chrome_options=chrome_options)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py",
>   line 81, in **init**
>       desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 157, in **init**
>       self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 252, in start_session
>       response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
>   Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally   (unknown error:
>   DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The process started from
>   chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so
>   ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.44.609551
>   (5d576e9a44fe4c5b6a07e568f1ebc753f1214634),platform=Linux
>   4.15.0-60-generic x86_64)

Comment: Please check your code and copy/paste it again, there is some duplicated content.

Comment: Thank you, yes I had pasted it twice, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of errors I cansee for now:

1) you have to uncomment chrome options and comment firefox' as you're passing the chromedriver later in code

```
# from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

Btw, that pyvirtualdisplay is an alternative for *headless* chrome, you don't need it imported.

2) you have instantiated Options two times and you're using only the first one. Change your code to:

```
def init_selenium():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage') 
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
```

I guess these two are just for start, edit your question when you encounter the next problem you can't solve.

Answer (score 1):

You are using chrome driver, but you comment it out at import.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

In the search function, the process is:
get page -> find search box -> input value -> enter keys -> grab results.

Something like this:

```
def search_for_title(title):
    driver.get('https://www.goodreads.com/search?q=')
    search_field = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    search_field.clear()
    search_field.send_keys(title)
    search_field.send_keys(keys.Keys.RETURN) # you missed this part
    url = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a')
    print(url.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: Great! Thank you, this is now working for the first item on my list, but it stoppes running after than, any ideas?

Comment: @ThelmarGeraldashk maybe the sleep(30) in init_selenium() ?